# How to 'call' datagridview event CellValueChanged from within another method?

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

The current code uses ...

1 = `dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(){ //do some stuff }`
2 = `dataGridView1_RowLeave(){ //do some other stuff }`

If user changes a cell value, then mouse clicks elsewhere, the sequence is 1,2 ... everything is all good.

However, if user changes a cell value, then presses the enter key, the sequence is 2, 1

I need cellValueChanged to fire BEFORE RowLeave()

Thanks in advance

/////////////////////

Here is the requested code

```
dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
newRecord = listOfRecords.ElementAt(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
_recordsHaveChanged = true;
}

dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
if (_recordsHaveChanged)
{
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("yes or no", "",     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
UpdateChanges.PerformClick();
_recordsHaveChanged = false;
DisplayAllDataOnTheForm();
}
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
//do nothing , return to form
}
}
}
```

Comment: Put the `{ //do some stuff } ` code in its own method and call it from the 2 places.  dont try to invoke events manually

Comment: I think `CellValueChanged` must be fired (based on fact that `RowLeave` event was fired). Can you show the code of `CellValueChanged` eventhandler or how you check that `CellValueChanged` event was fired or not?

Comment: @Fabio, I was wrong.  CellValueChanged does fire, but it does so AFTER RowLeave.  I need it to fire BEFORE RowLeave.

Comment: Since both events get fired in both situations. Could you not simply disable the rowLeave event and call it from the CellValueChanged event? This way CellValueChanged will always get fired first.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the dataGridView1_KeyPress event. Place `{ //do some stuff }` code in this event as well.

Or even better create another method with `{ //do some stuff }` and call it from both dataGridView1_KeyPress and dataGridView1_CellValueChanged events.